# Kotlin: Incompatible types: String and Int

Tags: kotlin

I tried to code this in Kotlin:

```
fun main() {
    val number = 9

    when (number) {
        is String -> println("Number is String")
        !is String -> println("Number is not String")
    }
}
```

But an error appears: `Incompatible types: String and Int`.
Shouldn't what should appear is the words: "Number is not String"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lukman nudin mentioned, `Koltin` will auto cast variable type based on initialisation value/type, so
the statement `val number = 9` is equivalent to `val number: Int = 9`, meaning you are strictly casting it to `Int` and trying to check instance of `String`, it will fail, so you need to use `Any` explicitly `val number:Any = 9`

```
fun main() {
    val number:Any = 9
    when (number) {
        is String -> println("Number is String")
        else -> println("Number is not String")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because your IDE already know number is integer, so IDE will tell its incompatible, try this on

```
fun main(any: Any){
    when (any){
        is String -> {}
        is Int -> {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Using anything other than a string array as the arguments to `main()` is a bit weird. This will prevent the function from being runnable in IntelliJ, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`Incompatible types: String and Int` is not something the program prints; it's a compiler error.

`Number is not String` is what would appear if you *ran* the program. But you can't run it because it doesn't compile.

And the reason it doesn't compile is because the compiler developers think that trying to check if an `Int` is a `String` is very likely a programmer error, so it's better to give you a chance to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example:

```
if (9 is String) println("9 is a string")
```

`9 is String` can never be `true`.

The `is` operator is a *runtime* check, to check the type of an object. But here the compiler knows here at *compile* time that the runtime check is useless, which means you probably made a logical error.